# What exactly is the output of a keccak256() function?

Tags: solidity, hash, keccak, hash-algorithm

I've been looking through articles and youtube videos and I still don't get it.

I'm trying to get to a place where I can explain it to myself in simple terms (I'm still pretty new to coding).

What I have so far is:

"keccak256() maps the input into a random 256-bit hexadecimal number."

I don't yet understand what the output exactly is.

Using a keccak256 hash generator, I know it's supposed to look something like this:

97fc46276c172633607a331542609db1e3da793fca183d594ed5a61803a10792

hexadecimal -> numbers that uses the base-16 system (This part I understand, and I can see it in the address.)

256-bit -> 256 binary digits (This part I don't. I'm not seeing how it relates to the output.)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To preface, let's talk about hex.

Hexadecimal is just a representation of a value. So the hexadecimal representation of the binary number `1100` is `C`. You can verify this by first converting `1100` in binary to decimal (it's `1 * 8 + 1 * 4 = 12`) and then converting that into hexadecimal which gives us `C`.

So `1100` in binary is `C` in hexadecimal which is also `12` in decimal (and it's `14` in octal, and whatever else you want in whatever base you choose!)

---

With that out of the way, let's think about what exactly "256-bit hexadecimal number" means.

Well we already know what a "hexadecimal number is", it's a representation of a number using base-16 (the hex base). So that means we should expect the output to be formatted a hexadecimal number. But we haven't talked at all about *what* that hexadecimal number is!

256-bit is talking about the *size* of the number that will be returned. I could have just as easily said 32-byte or 64-[nibble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble) hexadecimal number. So being a 256-bit number, it can only hold values between `0` and `2^256 - 1` (if we are assuming the number is not signed).

If you look at your hex output `97fc46276c172633607a331542609db1e3da793fca183d594ed5a61803a10792` and count the number of characters there are there, you'll count 64. Each hex character represents 4 bits, so we have 256 bits represented here!

Comment: Thank you so much - that really clears it up. In your last paragraph though, did you mean 64 characters? (and not 32)

Comment: Oh yes! Sorry :) I edited the answer. Clearly I can't count properly :P

Comment: @ZiyadEdher You gave so much incorrect info in this answer it's unbelievable. First you say `1100` in binary  is `F` in hex which it isn't - it's `C`. Then you somehow managed to convert `1000` binary to `12` in decimal which is again false - it's `8`. Then you go on to say that `1100` is `B` in hex which contradicts with your first statement that `1100` =`F` which is again incorrect, it's `C`.

Comment: Looks like I flip-flopped on what constants to use and got my wires crossed :) Caching, huh. Thanks for the heads-up, I updated my answer! Also, I don't think there's any need to be aggressive about it, we're all in this together.

Answer (score 2):

`keccak256` is a *secure hash function*. It returns a *fingerprint* of its input data, the fingerprint is 256 bits in length.

The Keccak is a family of secure hash algorithm that were standardized as [SHA-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3).

A *secure hash function*, like keccak, has some properties:

- Given the `output` it is hard to get the `input`, input = keccak256<sup>-1</sup>(output)
- It is hard to get two inputs that produce the same output, keccak256(input1) == keccak256(input2).